# AJAX request is not correct

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm a newbie to AJAX. I want to write value of radio button in a file through JavaScript, which is not possible according to my search. For that purpose, I'm sending an AJAX request to a function of php. Following is my AJAX request.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/modules/orffinder/write_file",
     type: "POST",
     data: "id=radios[i].value",
     success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
     window.opener.runNextModule (msg);
 }
 });
```

My php function is

```
function write_file()
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo "The id is ".$id;
    $myFile = "/var/www/Bioinfo12/testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $id);
    fclose($fh);
 }
```

but the problem with this code is that it does not run at all, may be its a syntax error. How to get out of this problem?

Comment: If there is a syntax error, then it will be reported in your browser's error console (if it is a JS error) or the server's error log (if it is a PHP error). What do they say?

Comment: @Quentin there is no error shown in browser or on server.

Comment: Then it isn't a syntax error (or you aren't looking in the right place). What does your browser's network tab say? Is the HTTP request that you expect to be made being made? Does it get the response you expect it to get? What happens if you make that request manually?

Comment: what is your structe of dir?

Comment: @Quentin actuall i am calling a js function after success of ajax. without this code that function is called. if i write this code of ajax it reloads my php controller. (as working in code igniter)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use var in " " in js,You shoule do like this:

```
data: "id="+radios[i].value
```

You can see your error in browser consle, for example F12 in chrome.

There are some reasons :

```
1.the url is not right "module/xxxx" is diffrent from "/module/xxxx"

2.the php script occur error.
```

So you can get infomation from browser, to see is 404, or the php return error info

Oh... in php:

```
echo "The id is ".id;
```

shoule be :

```
echo "the id is ". $id
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass a string to `data` at all, it is much better served with an object (`data: { id: radios[i].value }`) — but this can't be the (current) problem. The question says "it does not run at all" not that the given value is wrong.

Comment: there are no errors shown in console. data: "id="+radios[i].value has also no affect on results.

Comment: @ayankhan in php , not id , should be $id

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL for the PHP file correct? There should be a PHP extension.
"modules/orffinder.php"

Javascript is unable to call PHP functions directly. The `write_file` function should be called automatically whenever the page is visited.

Comment: There are numerous ways to have a URI handled by PHP without including the characters `.php` in the URI itself.

Comment: write_file is a function of orffinder.php, should i write it as modules/orffinder.php/write_file ?

Comment: @ayan You don't need to reference the PHP function to call (Javascript is unable to do anything on the server): Asynch Javascript just returns the output of the page. If anything, write_file should execute automatically when the page is requested.

Comment: @Quentin while true, I'm almost positive that isn't the case here.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney i have called function of php from js in the same way. it works perfectly for other function in same php file. problem is with this ajax and function.

Comment: @ayan When you visit the "modules/orffinder.php" page in your browser, what do you see? Whatever you see will be what the `xmlhttprequest` will see.